# What defines the order of the tabs in the new template window?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2010

When using the templates feature in Microsoft Office, what is it that defines the order in which the sub-folders in your defined templates folder are displayed?

At this point I would post an image but I don't have the rep.

The window I mean is accessed via File>New>My Templates

So far I've worked out it's not the name of the folder, not the folder creation/modification date and not the amount of items in the folder.